# auto currency switch not working on nginx with varnish cache in magento

Tags: magento, nginx, varnish

we have magento store with multi currency . we have integrated auto-currency switch extension . That module work on IP address of customer. so now the currency not auto switching after enabling varnish cache to store. so please suggest what to do ? 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can try adding cache_lifetime for currency block

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the issue you are having is triggered by Varnish Cache.

Let me clarify. If you install and enable Varnich Cache, it will be able to send queries to Magento only once, until pages get cached. And when that happens, Varnish won't allow you to send more queries to a webserver with Magento.

Hence, to solve the issue, you need to transfer the switching currency also to the Vanish server.

First, you need to:

- Install libvmod-geoip: https://github.com/lampeh/libvmod-geoip
- Configure VCL to detect customer's country

There are several examples of how to get GeoIP while working with Varnish. Check out the blog posts below:

- http://blog.tenya.me/blog/2013/10/25/geoip-with-varnish/
- https://vrobert.fr/2010/07/another-way-to-link-varnish-and-maxmind-geoip/
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8058/geoip-based-default-currency-selection-behind-varnish

Hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not really an answer. But, I had the same issue. Varnish is the issue. We need to update its config.

Basically, we need to check the currency cookie (it can be a custom cookie) in your Varnish config.

For Magento, there is a good guide here:
https://medium.com/@wegrzynowiczk/magento-varnish-and-geoip-1e7fd713ef8

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "customer_geoip_currency=") {
    hash_data(regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*?customer_geoip_currency=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1"));
}
```

Comment: thank you for reviewing. Update my answer! It's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

After going crazy to find a solution for it, finally I got a working solution for Magento 2.3.2 + Varnish + GeoIP. To accomplish it you can use the `Cache Context` and `Page Variations` which are very simple to implement.

First create a Plugin into your module for `Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context`.

**File: app/code/Vendor/YourModule/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context">
        <plugin name="atwix_country_cache_context_plugin"
            type="Vendor\YourModule\Plugin\CustomerCountryCacheContextPlugin" />    
    </type>
</config>
```

Then the Plugin implementation

**File: Vendor/YourModule/Plugin/CustomerCountryCacheContextPlugin.php**

```
/**
 * Plugin on \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
 */
class CustomerCountryCacheContextPlugin
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    /**
     * \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context::getVaryString is used by Magento to retrieve unique identifier for selected context,
     * so this is a best place to declare custom context variables
     */
    function beforeGetVaryString(\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $subject)
    {
        $country = $this->yourWayToGetTheCountry();
        $defaultCountryContext = 'Brazil';
        $subject->setValue('CONTEXT_AGE', $country, $defaultCountryContext);
    }
}
```

And the last step is to add the `X-Magento-Vary` cookie to transfer context on the HTTP layer in your Varnish.

```
sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }
    ... more ...
}
```

For more info visit:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html#configure-page-variations

https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/cache-context-and-page-variations-in-magento-2/